# Android BluetoothLeScanner startScan not scanning in scheduleJob in android 7+ standbymode

Tags: android

I've build an android app which has to scans for Bluetooth devices every 15 minutes for a duration of 15 seconds. I expect my schedulejob to be triggered every 15 minutes (the minimum allowed time by android 7+), get a recent geolocation, scan for 15 seconds, and then send that list of devices with that specific geolocation to my backend. This procedure should also run even if the phone is in standby mode.

I've added logging to every step in the process to see what's actually being triggered and what not. My scheduleJob is actually running every 15 minutes as expected, but the scanning for BLE devices isn't being done. No error messages are displayed, but I can clearly see the scan process just isn't running.

To setup some tests, I've added a manual trigger to scan for devices and run the full process, when I do this, everything works as expected. So I think I can state that my setup to confirm permissions is done correctly and my location helper class is working properly (I confirmed this during the schedulejob process as well, I have successfully gotten a good location). I can confirm that the bluetooth system on my phone is working properly as the manual trigger does find my devices.

So it just seems like the startScan isn't running as I'd expect during the schedulejob. I've tested this on an Android 6, Android 7 and an Android 10, on the android 6 the scan does seem to work as expected even in standby modes, from the Android 7 onwards it doesn't work in standby mode anymore.
When the user keeps the app open and active for 15 minutes, the startscan does seem to trigger on the android 10.

For my scheduleJob I'm calling following method:

```java
public void scheduleJob(){
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, AppService.class);
        JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(123, componentName)
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setPersisted(true)
// 1000 * 60 * 2.5 => 2.5 minutes => Android will change this automatically to the minimum allowed => 15 minutes
                .setPeriodic(2500 * 60) 
                .build();
    }
```

For my permissions I have following:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

As for my startLeScan function, which I can confirm is being triggered

```java
   private void init() {
        if(mMapBleScanCallback == null) {
            mMapBleScanCallback = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
        }
        if(mHandler == null) {
            mHandler = new Handler();
        }
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        }
        if(mBluetoothLeScanner == null) {
            mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        }
        if(mScanSettingsBuilder == null) {
            mScanSettingsBuilder = new ScanSettings.Builder();
            mScanSettingsBuilder.setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED);
        }
   }

   public void startLeScan() {
        Log.d(TAG, "startLeScan");
        if(mBluetoothLeScanner == null) {
            mBluetoothLeScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
        }

        if(mBluetoothLeScanner != null && !mIsScanning) {
            mIsScanning = true;
            notifyCallback(Constants.BLE.CALLBACK_SCAN_START, null);
            //mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(getScanFilters(), mScanSettingsBuilder.build(), mScanCallback);

// I've set my filter to null 
// my scansettings are set to ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_BALANCED during init
            mBluetoothLeScanner.startScan(null, mScanSettingsBuilder.build(), mScanCallback); // I've set my filters to null
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    stopLeScan();
                }
            }, Constants.BLE.SCAN_PERIOD);
        }
    }
```

As for my callback, I've added logging when a device is detected. I can see in my logging during manual scan that devices are found, but not during the schedulejob, none are shown...

```java
   private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onScanResult: " + result.toString());
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            prepareScanResult(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            Log.d(TAG, "onScanFailed: errorcode: " + errorCode);
        }
    };
```

Here is an image of some of the logging:

[image: Here is an image of my loggings during both manual and jobschedule triggers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [an article](https://www.mindbowser.com/ble-issues-in-android-7-and-above/) (ref. to point 1) which mentions that Samsung phones with Android 7+ don't allow scanning without a minimum of 1 scanfilter. And indeed, after implementing at least one scanfilter, everything started to work properly.